# How to set 3D cursor to origin

Tags: object-mode

I did have the Origin and 3D cursor at the same location but somehow I have now got the 3D cursor elsewhere.
Is there a way to set the 3D cursor to the origin (I know how to set the Origin to the 3D cursor but not the other way).

[image]

Comment: to get 3D cursor to the origin press `Shift`+`C` or press `N` to open the N-pannel and under View tab, you can adjust the position of the 3D cursor as well.

Comment: Although setting the 3D cursor to the World origin has been explained to you by @HarryMcKenzie, you probably originally moved it in error by Shift right-clicking with the mouse.

Comment: and Shift S to put the 3D cursor at the same location as the origin of an object

Comment: Thanks everyone. I couldn't find the 3D cursor in the transform panel (in v3.1).  I did though use shift S and  then selected (using intuition/guess work) Cursor to Active. Thanks again for helping me get my brain into gear (it was is reverse I think :-(  )   Refer to image I have now added to my question showing before I did Cursor to Active.

Comment: Oops.  I made a mistake the 3d cursor position IS under teh view tab of the transform panel